# Plotting a subset of time series' points in Julia

Tags: dataframe, plot, time-series, julia

I have a time series with records for years 1975-1985 and 2000-2005. I would like to have a single plot with only these years on it, i.e. without all the years 1986-1999 in between. On top of this, I'd like the years 1985 and 2000 to be not connected, and of different color.

Unfortunately, I only manage to produce a plot with all the years included. I am using Dataframes and Plots packages. Does anyone maybe know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from your question what your data looks like (are there `missing`s in 1986-99?) and what your expected output is (do you want a gap in the middle of the plot?) but here are a couple of options:

```
# Packages to use
using Dates, DataFrames, Plots

# Example data
df = DataFrame(date = Date(1975):Year(1):Date(2005),
               data = rand(31))

# Option 1 - plot with no data in the middle (straight line interpolation)
plot(df[.!in(1986:1999).(year.(df.date)), :date], 
     df[.!in(1986:1999).(year.(df.date)), :data])
```

[image: Option 1]

```
# Option 2 - plot line in two parts with gap in the middle
plot(df[in(1970:1985).(year.(df.date)), :date],
     df[in(1970:1985).(year.(df.date)), :data], color = "blue")
 plot!(df[in(2000:2015).(year.(df.date)), :date],
      df[in(2000:2015).(year.(df.date)), :data], label = "", color = "blue")
```

[image: Option2]

```
# Option 3 - plot continuous line and generate xticks manually
plot(df[.!in(1986:1999).(year.(df.date)), :data],
    xticks = (1:length(df[.!in(1986:1999).(year.(df.date)), :date]),
            year.(df[.!in(1986:1999).(year.(df.date)), :date])))
```

[image: Option 3]

EDITED TO ADD:

If the data is actually missing, then option 3 can be produced even more simply by doing:

```
# Create example column with missing data 
df[:, :data_missing] = allowmissing(df.data)
df[in(1986:1999).(year.(df.date)), :data_missing] .= missing

# Plot option 3 
plot(df.date, df.data_missing)
```

EDITED AGAIN TO ADD:
Finally if you want a gap in between the two and different colours, you need a variation of option 2:

```
plot(df[in([1970:1986; 2000:2015]).(year.(df.date)), :data_missing])
plot!(13:18, df[in(2000:2015).(year.(df.date)), :data_missing], label = "",
    xticks = (1:18, year.(df[in([1970:1986; 2000:2015]).(year.(df.date)), :date])))
```

[image: Option 4]

Comment: Thanks Nils. Yes, the data for 86-99 is missing. I precisely do not want the plot to look like options 1 and 2.

Comment: In that case it should be even easier to produce option 3 - see my edit above.

Comment: I want it to like similar to Option 3, but with years 1985 and 2000 not being connected and being of different color. I have been playing with the code trying to get sth like this, but I am failing again. Maybe you can help?

Comment: Have added another option